# Artoolkit can not load texture file in Android

Tags: android, artoolkit

I try to replace the model in ARSimpleNativeCarsProj the Android example, put the .obj, .mtl and texture file into models folder, I changed the version code also.But I got an error:

> 02-17 09:09:24.737
>   12711-12986/org.artoolkit.ar.samples.ARSimpleNativeCars E/libeden:
>   ReadTex(): Can't open file 'Data/models/solid/Basketweave.jpg' for
>   reading. 02-17 09:09:24.737
>   12711-12986/org.artoolkit.ar.samples.ARSimpleNativeCars E/libeden: No
>   such file or directory 02-17 09:09:24.737
>   12711-12986/org.artoolkit.ar.samples.ARSimpleNativeCars E/libeden:
>   EdenSurfacesTextureLoad(): Unable to read file
>   'Data/models/solid/Basketweave.jpg'. 02-17 09:09:24.737
>   12711-12986/org.artoolkit.ar.samples.ARSimpleNativeCars E/libeden:
>   EdenSurfacesTextureLoad() couldn't read texture file
>   "Data/models/solid/Basketweave.jpg". 02-17 09:09:24.737
>   12711-12986/org.artoolkit.ar.samples.ARSimpleNativeCars E/libeden:
>   glmDrawArrays(): Error loading texture.

Could somebody help me?Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the jpg file is not located in the right directory. Can you share your directory structure somehow?

Comment: The jpg file is in the right place.The problem is the different format between windows and linux,[Here](https://github.com/artoolkit/artoolkit5/issues/256)  is more information.